# Как изменить адрес репозитория maven в Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, settings

Я использую Intellij Idea 15.0.6. И хочу изменить адрес Maven-репозитория с https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ на http://search.maven.org/ (вроде как последний более актуальный). Но когда я захожу в настройки Intellij Idea (Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Repositories) поле с адресом центрального репозитория:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно только выделить, но изменить нельзя. Можно ли как-либо изменить эту настройку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://search.maven.org/ - это интерфейс для поиска по репозиторию https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/

Для добавления репозитория в Maven проект надо в pom.xml добавить:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>NAME</id>
        <url>URL/url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: А какие тогда другие альтернативы https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ могут быть? Просто в этом репозитории не могу найти библиотеки, которые вроде как раньше там были...